# How to access a SBT project's settings in a plugin?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'd like to access the name of a SBT project that uses a plugin in the plugin.

Within `build.sbt` I have the following:

```
name := "x_include"
```

I assumed obtaining this would be rather straight forward via use of `name.key.label`. This piece of code, however returns the default name of the project, 'name' , specified in SBT's `Keys.scala`.

I initially thought it may have been some sort of loading/timing issue, however that seems unlikely due to the following console output:

```
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/ndidialaneme/.sbt/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/ndidialaneme/Sandbox/sbt-docbook-plugin/src/sbt-test/docbook/x_include/project
[info] Set current project to x_include (in build file:/Users/ndidialaneme/Sandbox/sbt-docbook-plugin/src/sbt-test/docbook/x_include/)
[info] Updating {file:/Users/ndidialaneme/Sandbox/sbt-docbook-plugin/src/sbt-test/docbook/x_include/}default-b1b964...
    ...
[info] ****  Project: name
```

The third line in the above output clearly uses my project name while, the last line does not.

Any advice?

---

UPDATE:

Paul Butcher's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973666/accessing-sbt-project-settings/8973729#8973729) correctly answer's my question, however my question is poorly worded.

I'm working on an SBT plugin. The name being returned to me is, understandably, the name of the plugin. What I actually need it to return is the name of the project that uses the plugin. I can already see that this adds a fair amount of complexity, however I don't think it should be impossible to implement.

Hopefully the SBT api/documentation along with the [xsbt-reflect](https://github.com/ritschwumm/xsbt-reflect) code should help me resolve this.

Comment: This answer may be very relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50436200/5704808

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [xsbt-reflect](https://github.com/ritschwumm/xsbt-reflect).

Comment: Thanks. I'll implement it now. I am curious, though, as to why this functionality isn't part of SBT. Hmm.. Maybe in a future version.

Comment: So an sbt plugin cannot directly access the name of the project it is being applied to? let alone in multi-project builds? has sbt been enhanced with this capability in recent versions?